# Different boost serialization header version for 'same' code

Tags: c++, matlab, serialization, boost, mex

I have a strange problem loading some archive data between different architectures. To be precise: I am serializing a struct in my c++ code (which is saved with an archive version of 10). 
This archive should then be deserialized within my matlab mex project, but this fails due to version conflicts

> Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file. What() is:unsupported
>   version

After that, I serialized the same struct in my MEX project. This resulted in an archive version of 9. 
To verify, if different boost versions were used during compilation, I printed out the following MACRO in both projects

```
cout << "BOOST VERSION " << BOOST_VERSION << endl;
```

In both codes, the cpp project and the MEX project, version **105500** was returned. I also used the *ldd* command to verify, if the binaries are linked to the correct library and they are

> ldd testFooMex.mexa64 
>           libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0 => /home/PATH/TO/Libraries/boost/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f52d5149000)
>
> ldd test.exe
>           libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0 => /home/PATH/TO/Libraries/boost/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f52d5149000)

If I manually change the version number from 10 to 9 in the text archive, my struct can be deserialized in the MEX project without any issues.

Do you guys have any idea, why different versions are used even though I am using the **same** boost version?

Here are some code snippets. In both projects (which are based on [this post](http://marc.info/?l=boost-users&m=128780145701934)), I use the same *Header.h*

```
#ifndef Test_h
#define Test_h
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
typedef boost::archive::text_oarchive OutputArchive;
typedef boost::archive::text_iarchive InputArchive;

struct Test
{
private:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t );
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template<typename Archive>
  void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int version )
  {
    ar & i;
    ar & d;
    ar & *p;

  }

public:
  int i;
  double d;
  double* p;

  Test()
  {
    p=new double;
  }

  Test( int _i, double _d )
  {
    i=_i;
    d=_d;
    p = new double;
    *p=d*2;
  }
  ~Test(){ delete p; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Test& t )
{
  os << t.i << ", " << t.d << ",  " << *(t.p) << std::endl;
}

#endif Test_h
```

*test.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Test.h"
#include "boost/version.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "BOOST VERSION " << BOOST_VERSION << endl;
  Test t(1,0.1);
  {
    std::ofstream ofs("serialize.txt");
    OutputArchive oa(ofs);
    oa << t;
  }
  cout << "original : " << t;

  {
    ifstream ifs("serialize.txt",ios_base::in);
    InputArchive ia(ifs);
    Test t2;
    cout << "ready to import..." << flush;
    ia >> t2;
    cout << "done" << endl;
    cout << "restored : " << t2;
  }
}
```

*testFooMex.cpp*

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "Test.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "boost/version.hpp"

using namespace std;

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
  // FAILS TO LOAD FILE WITH VERSION 10
  cout << "BOOST VERSION " << BOOST_VERSION << endl;
  Test t;
  ifstream in( "serialize.txt", ios_base::in );
  InputArchive ia(in);
  ia >> t;
  mexPrintf("%i\n",t.i);
  mexPrintf("%f\n",t.d);
  mexPrintf("%f\n",*(t.p));


 /* GENERATES THE SAME FILE WITH VERSION 9
 Test t(1,0.1);
  {
    std::ofstream ofs("serialize.out");
    OutputArchive oa(ofs);
    oa << t;
  }
  cout << "original : " << t;

  {
    ifstream ifs("serialize.out",ios_base::in);
    InputArchive ia(ifs);
    Test t2;
    cout << "ready to import..." << flush;
    ia >> t2;
    cout << "done" << endl;
    cout << "restored : " << t2;
  } */
}
```

Comment: boost version is not the same as archive version. As far as I can see you're not specifying the archive version anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure about that or are you talking about the class version which can be set manually and is 0 by default? I have not found anything about how to change the archive version

Comment: He seems to mean the archive version specified here: https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/blob/boost-1.55.0/src/basic_archive.cpp. You're right about this not being something for the user to change. Seems like version 10 appeared first in boost 1.53.

Comment: @RichardHodges archive version is an implementation detail of the boost library version.

Comment: @sehe ah of course. I was thinking of the class version. Boost docs are quite explicit about not relying on compatibility between implementation versions, or different systems IIRC

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes. But that's supposedly not applicable here. Of course, that probably means Observer Error

Comment: I suppose the question is what libraries are loaded when `testFooMex.mexa64` is loaded by Matlab? @Cr3at0rX What if you link with boost statically?

Comment: @dan-mašek This is indeed a good question. Since Matlab uses the same PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables, there should not be any differences except the matlab related libraries. I'm not sure if this will help, but I can give it a try.

Comment: MATLAB probably loads its own Boost library, which is different from the one installed system-wide. You can check by comparing the output of `ldd` run from both inside and outside MATLAB (i.e use `system('ldd ...')` vs `ldd` in a terminal). You could try force-loading your version by starting MATLAB with the `LD_PRELOAD` set accordingly, but no guarantees it doesnt mess up with MATLAB own dependencies...